# How to remove scrolling behavior for child AppBarLayout/TabLayout only?

Tags: android, android-tablayout, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

I have a main activity that I use for all my activities which has this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            style="@style/ToolBar"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And inside of one of my fragments I have this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs_app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            style="@style/TabLayout"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Is it possible I can disable the `Scrolling View Behavior` for the `@+id/tabs_app_bar_layout` only? Basically I have two `AppBarLayout`s, one for the `Toolbar` and one for bottom navigation tabs. I want the scrolling view behavior to only affect the `Toolbar`.

What is the best way I can disable the scrolling behavior for only certain child views?

Comment: Have you found something?